# Normal subgroup of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $U \leq G = A \times B$ such that $N_G(U) = \pi_A(N_G(U)) \times \pi_B(N_G(U))$ where $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are the respective projection maps.

Using the well-known generalization of normal subgroups of direct products since $U \unlhd \pi_A(N_G(U)) \times \pi_B(N_G(U))$, we get that $\pi_X(U)/ X \cap U$ is abelian for $X = A,B$.

I need to show that $U \unlhd \pi_A(U) \times \pi_B(U)$. I'm not sure how to use the abelian part to prove this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but that seems clear from $U \le N_G(U)$.

Comment: Note that it is sufficient to show that $\pi_1(U)\times \pi_2(U) \leq \pi_1(N_G(U))\times \pi_2(N_G(U))=N_G(U)$.

Comment: @Nex I can see why that would be sufficient but won't I need to show that $U \leq \pi_A(U) \times \pi_B(U)$?

Comment: But that is always true. If $(a,b) \in U$, then $a \in \pi_1(U)$ and $b \in \pi_2(U)$.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks! Since $\pi_X(U) \leq \pi_X(N_G(U))$ for $X =A, B$ it should follow the easily that $\pi_A (U)\times \pi_B(U) \leq \pi_A(N_G(U))\times \pi_B(N_G(U))=N_G(U)$. Is the correct reasoning?